# How can I require login whilst running on a custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app running on Google AppEngine on a Google Apps domain.

In my `app.yaml`, I have the following:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27

...

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index\.html
  login: required
  secure: always

- url: /foo
  script: foo.app
  login: required
  secure: always
```

When I go to https:// myapp.mydomain.com/, I am correctly redirected to Google's login screen. When I go to https:// 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com/foo, I am also redirected to Google's login screen.

However, when I go to https:// myapp.mydomain.com/foo, I can proceed without authentication.

I actually believe that this is a regression and that it has been working correctly up until recently, but just in case, am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're missing is:

- If appid.domain.com/ is accessed and user signs in -> no sign in is
  required to access appid.domain.com/foo as user was already
  identified when accessing appid.domain.com/ (session cookie).
- If appid.domain.com/foo is accessed in incognito or after clearing cache and cookies -> sign in is required.

Please let me know if appid.domain.com/foo doesn't require sign-in when accessed in incognito mode / after clearing browsing data.

Comment: That's correct. Even in incognito mode, appid.domain.com/foo, which I have specified to require login, is not prompting for login.

Comment: Can you add `from google.appengine.api import users`, `import logging`, `users.get_current_user()` and check what user is being reported.

Comment: I meant `logging.info(users.get_current_user())` after importing the logging module to see if any user is being reported as signed in.

Comment: Have you tried to add `from google.appengine.api import users`, 'import logging' and 'logging.info(users.get_current_user())' to your foo.py? Do you mind sharing it?